Does "refurbished" imply battery replacement?
Bought a refurbished Macbook Pro April 2023 from an "authorized" shop.  I don't know whether they or Apple did the refurbishing, but it was eligible for the "trade-in" of my older one.
The battery only lasts one or two hours of light use, suggesting it was not replaced.  Should it have been?

Apple sell refurbished directly and it comes with a full 1 year warranty (bought a couple and used the warranty once so I know).
If you bought from an "authorised" store then you will either have guarantee information with the purchase which you should know, if not then you "might" have some warranty with the shop. Up to you to get back there and find out.
Did you check the cycles count on the battery before purchase? Based on you not replaying to my comment on your other question you probably missed that.
I just bought an M2 refurbished from Apple and it had a cycle count of 2 iirc - which I thought valid if they had tested it...

I don't know whether I have warranty information—I'd have to locate the sixteen-month-old paperwork.  Since it's over a year, I doubt it.  I don't always reply immediately to comments because I don't keep an SE window open constantly.  Or, as you say, it was while typing this :-)

Or you were just writing this question...
